# Concrete basement: Do I need a sealer or wax only?

Tags: concrete, sealer

I'm going to acid stain my concrete basement floor.  Do I NEED a sealer, or can I simply apply wax directly to the concrete (which intuitively would act as the sealer itself)?

Comment: Both work. Wax is more maintenance. We acid stained our basement and ended up going with a non-epoxy sealer (which worked fine, but epoxy options tend to be the longest lasting)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need a sealer.  Wax wears off so fast that the maintenance would be unbearable.